# Django ajax-selects package is not working. What I am missing?

Tags: django, django-ajax-selects

I am trying to use Django ajax-selects package 
I have my form.py :

```
from ajax_select.fields import AutoCompleteSelectField, AutoCompleteSelectMultipleField
from ajax_select import make_ajax_field
class LeaseTenantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LeaseTenant
        exclude = []
    tenant  = make_ajax_field(LeaseTenant,'tenant','tenant',help_text="Search for label by name") 
    #tenant = AutoCompleteSelectField('tenant', required=False, help_text=None)
```

I have my lookup.py:

```
from ajax_select import register, LookupChannel
from client.models import Tenant

@register('tenant')
class TenantLookup(LookupChannel):

    model = Tenant

    def get_query(self, q, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(last_name=q)

    def format_item_display(self, item):
        return u"<span class='tag'>%s</span>" % item.last_name
```

I have my tenant model.py:

```
class Tenant(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='E',
                              choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
    external_address = models.CharField(max_length=90,null=True, blank=True)
    external_zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    external_city = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True, blank=True)
    external_state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    external_country = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='N',
                              choices=TENANT_STATUS_CHOICES,null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %i %s %s %s %s %s %s' % ("#", self.id,"first_name", self.first_name, "last_name",  self.last_name, "phone", self.phone )
```

But in my form I am not getting no autocomplete and no field create.
What have I missed?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the fact that your filter in get_query appears to be using a field that doesn't exist in the Tenant class.  If that's not it some diags (e.g. requests/responses) from when you load the form and enter some text would help.

Comment: You right the field name was wrong . I copied the wrong version. But this is not the problem.

Comment: Now your filter is an exact match...  Don't you want some other possible options (and so want to use contains or startswith)?

Comment: the problem is that nothing happens when I input any values and I dont see any error.

Comment: Which is all very plausible when you are looking for an exact match - I would expect no results until you have typed in exactly the right name.

Comment: This might be a silly question but you did add the ajax_select_urls in your project's urls.py, right?

Comment: @Vlad B  No question is silly:). Yes I did

Comment: you probably shouldn't be using an exact match in an autocomplete lookup it's kind of counterintuitive. You should be using something like an __icontains at the bare minimum

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using an exact match query. Autocomplete behavior is inexact. You have:

```
def get_query(self, q, request):
    return self.model.objects.filter(last_name=q)
```

You're probably intending something to the effect of:

```
def get_query(self, q, request):
    return self.model.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=q)
```